# duplicate char* in C

Tags: c, string, duplicates

Hello I am trying to create a hash function in C to remove duplicates from a set of strings a.k.a char*. The idea is to make what the hash function returns, to be the index of  an array, so that if two strings are same they point to the same position at the array. But I am stuck at how could I achieve that.

On my first approach I tried to create an array of integers with size equal to the number of strings given and then make the int, that the hash function returns, modulo the size of the array but it didn't worked since for small number of strings many collisions were created.

**To sum up**, all I want is to implement a structure, probably a hashMap that getting an string will point me to a number, which is the index of the array, in which I store the number of occurences.

Is there any better idea?

Comment: Your array size should be a prime number.

Comment: @Zaffy so you suggest I find the closer, bigger, than the number of strings prime number?

Comment: Yeah, because if your array size is not a prime, you'll experience lots of collisions, just like now.

Comment: The answers to this question [Which hashing algorithm is best for uniqueness and speed?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/which-hashing-algorithm-is-best-for-uniqueness-and-speed) maybe helpful.

Comment: @Zaffy: But how can you know the number of different words that may come up in a text segment?

Comment: You will use the solution like `hash % size` but size will be prime number; give it a try.

Comment: For a hash function with a reasonable spread (particularly in the lower bits) prime sized tables are not needed. BTW when placing N items in N slots the chance of collision reaches 1. (pigeon-hole)

Comment: @wildplasser I tried what you suggest but I had many collisions

Comment: Having a few collisions should be acceptable. And show your code if you want more help.

Comment: Even with an ideal randomlly spread hash function, placing N items into N slots will cause _about_ 1/3 of the cells to be empty, 1/3 having one item, and 1/3 more than one item.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want [string interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning). Some libraries call them "quarks" (e.g. [Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Quarks.html)) or "atoms" (like in X11: [XInternAtom](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XInternAtom.html)). See also [symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_%28programming%29) (e.g. in Lisp or Scheme).

You could store all your interned strings in a global hash table, and have some function

```
const char* internized_string(const char*str);
```

which given some string `str` returns a canonical interned string which compare equals (with `strcmp`) to it. But two calls of `interned_string` on equal (but not identical) strings would return the same address. It would work by first searching a similar string in the hash table; if none is found, add a new copy (perhaps using `strdup`) into the hash table, and return it.

You could use an [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), a [balanced tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_tree) (i.e. [red black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_black_tree) or an [AVL tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) etc....) a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), or a [hash array mapped trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_array_mapped_trie), or any efficient [container](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Container_%28abstract_data_type%29) to implement your global collection of interned strings.

BTW, if you coded in [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11), you'll have many standard [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) provided by the standard C++ library.

If you want to code all by yourself, you could have an hash table implemented as array of [buckets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_%28computing%29); usually you want the size of the array to be prime. Each bucket could be a linked list, or a contiguous array, of string pointers. You re-organize your entire hash table when it gets full (e.g. when the mean -or perhaps the max- size of buckets reaches some threshold like 3 or 8) by growing the bucket array to a bigger prime size -e.g. a prime greater than 3/2 of the old one- (and refill the new table from the old one). Avoid [collisions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution) (but accept to have a few of them).

There are many hash table free software libraries in C; e.g. [uthash](http://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/), [klib](https://github.com/attractivechaos/klib), [tommyds](http://tommyds.sourceforge.net/), [ulib](http://code.google.com/p/ulib/), [libstrhash](https://ohse.de/uwe/strhash/libstrhash.html), [glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html) etc etc... GIYF. Study (at least for inspiration) the source code of some of them, and perhaps use one.